# Cron environment variables

Tags: bash, cron

I'm running a simple shell script that runs just fine in a login shell from `cron`, where it doesn't run. For some reason, `/usr/local/bin` is not on the users path when run from `cron` while it is when run in a shell.

Where is the environment for `cron` determined?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, from the non-login environment established for `/bin/sh`, which is the default used to run the command.

You can set additional environment variables in your crontab in most versions, vis:

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
@reboot whatever
```

Check `crontab(5)` for details; `man 5 crontab`

Answer (score 0):

Check which shell your script is using.

The shell and variables for crontab are specified in /etc/crontab

```
x@x:~$ cat /etc/crontab 

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

The profile file used by sh is in user home.

```
x@x:~$ ls ~/.profile 
/home/x/.profile
```

You can add PATH variable in end of this file (Make sure you are adding in profile file of correct user)

```
PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin"
```

or you can add the same line in your own script.